# Calling a Google cloud function within Airflow DAG

Tags: python, google-cloud-functions, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I have a google cloud function that is working, I am trying to call it from an Airflow DAG.

what I have tried so far is to use the SimpleHttpOperator:

```
MY_TASK_NAME = SimpleHttpOperator(
        task_id= "MY_TASK_NAME",
        method='POST',
        http_conn_id='http_default',
        endpoint='https://us-central1-myprojectname.cloudfunctions.net/MyFunctionName',
        data=({"schema": schema, "table": table}),
        headers={"Content-Type": "application/json"},
        xcom_push=False
    )
```

but digging into the logs, it says it cannot find the resource:

> {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask:
>
> The requested URL `/https://us-central1-myprojectname.cloudfunctions.net/MyFunctionName` was not found on this server.  That’s all we know.

also I noticed that it actually posts to https://www.google.com/ + the url I gave:

```
Sending 'POST' to url: https://www.google.com/https://us-central1-myprojectname.cloudfunctions.net/MyFunctionName
```

what is the proper way to call the function ?
Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70174703/10375049

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are using the `http_conn_id='http_default'`.

The `http_default` connection looks as follows:

[image]

If you check the Hosts field, it says `http://www.google.com/`.

Either create a new Connection with `HTTP` Connection type or modify the `http_default` connection and change the host to `https://us-central1-myprojectname.cloudfunctions.net/`

Then update the `endpoint` field in your task to:

```
MY_TASK_NAME = SimpleHttpOperator(
        task_id= "MY_TASK_NAME",
        method='POST',
        http_conn_id='http_default',
        endpoint='MyFunctionName',
        data=({"schema": schema, "table": table}),
        headers={"Content-Type": "application/json"},
        xcom_push=False
    )
```

Edit: Added / at the end of URLs

Comment: Thanks, it looks like I can call it now but I get a "ERROR - HTTP error: Forbidden", do you have an idea why it happens ?

Comment: Btw, it is a little detail but can you add a / at the end of the connection url, it needs one.

Comment: Yes you should be able to do that

Comment: @SylvainGantois Hi ,
Did this work for you?

Comment: @SnehilSingh, it did but it was 2 years ago, I cannot guarantee it's still working.

Comment: @SnehilSingh After fixing the URL, I recall I had authentication issues, so you might want to check the other answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

As @kaxil noted you need to first change the http connection. You then need to be able to send the correct authenticating for invoking the cloud function. The below link has a step by step guide for doing this by subclassing `SimpleHttpOperator`

https://medium.com/google-cloud/calling-cloud-composer-to-cloud-functions-and-back-again-securely-8e65d783acce

---

As a side note, Google should make this process much clearer. It is perfectly reasonable to want to trigger a Google Cloud Function (gcf) from Google Cloud Composer. The [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/http) for how to send an http trigger to a gcf includes documentation for Cloud Scheduler, Cloud Tasks, Cloud Pub/Sub, and a host of others but not Cloud Composer

Comment: Sadly, the link to the medium article is no-longer good.