# How to invoke a cloud function from google cloud composer?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, airflow, google-cloud-composer

For a requirement I want to call/invoke a cloud function from inside a cloud composer pipeline but I cant find much info on it, I tried using SimpleHTTP airflow operator but I get this error:

```
[2021-09-10 10:35:46,649] {taskinstance.py:1503} ERROR - Task failed with exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1158, in 
_run_raw_task
self._prepare_and_execute_task_with_callbacks(context, task)
File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1333, in 
_prepare_and_execute_task_with_callbacks
result = self._execute_task(context, task_copy)
File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1363, in 
_execute_task
result = task_copy.execute(context=context)
File "/home/airflow/gcs/dags/to_gcf.py", line 51, in execute
if not self.response_check(response):
File "/home/airflow/gcs/dags/to_gcf.py", line 83, in <lambda>
response_check=lambda response: False if len(response.json()) == 0 else True,
File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 900, in json
return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/json/__init__.py", line 357, in loads
return _default_decoder.decode(s)
File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
```

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I faced the same issue as you, but I managed to figure it out by studying the Airflow 2.0 provider packages for Google and using a PythonOperator instead.

```
from airflow.providers.google.common.utils import id_token_credentials as id_token_credential_utils
import google.auth.transport.requests
from google.auth.transport.requests import AuthorizedSession

def invoke_cloud_function():

  url = "<your_cloud_function_url>" #the url is also the target audience. 
  request = google.auth.transport.requests.Request()  #this is a request for obtaining the the credentials
  id_token_credentials = id_token_credential_utils.get_default_id_token_credentials(url, request=request) # If your cloud function url has query parameters, remove them before passing to the audience 

  resp = AuthorizedSession(id_token_credentials).request("GET", url=url) # the authorized session object is used to access the Cloud Function

  print(resp.status_code) # should return 200
  print(resp.content) # the body of the HTTP response
```

Thus, invoke the function as below:

```
    task = PythonOperator(task_id="invoke_cf", python_callable=invoke_cloud_function)
```

From my understanding, accessing an authenticated HTTP Cloud Function strictly requires a credential based on ID Tokens. Thus to obtain the required *type* of credentials, `get_default_id_token_credentials()` executes the Application Default Credentials(ADC) authorization flow, which is a process that obtains credentials from environment variables, known locations. or the Compute Engine metadata server. Composer should have the associated service account keyfile made avaliable via environment variables (probably `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`).

Once you have the right type of credentials, you can use the AuthorizedSessions object to authenticate your requests to the cloud function.

Comment: Hi @Seng Cheong I tried both these methods and am still getting connection timeout error on airflow , so cloud it be a internal gcp problem related to how resources are deployed or could it be that I am missing some packages ??

Comment: @SnehilSingh it is unlikely that your airflow environment lacks the packages needed to connect. Your error could stem from various causes e.g. VPN, Cloud Function configuration

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/_api/airflow/providers/google/cloud/operators/functions/index.html#airflow.providers.google.cloud.operators.functions.CloudFunctionInvokeFunctionOperator

Note that in order to use in 1.10 you need to have backport provider packages installed (but I believe they are installed by default) and version of the operator might be slightly different due to backport packages not being released for quite some time already.

In Airflow 2

Comment: Hi @JarekPotiuk,
I had tried the airflow invoke function operator but it didnt work , thats why I tried simpleHTTP operator.

Comment: It raises some bad request error every time i try to run it on airflow 
but using SimpleHttp operator I am able to invoke my cloud functions.

Answer (score 1):

Given a working Cloud Function in **HTTP** mode, the best and easy solution is to invoke it with `SimpleHttpOperator`.

If **authentication is required** by the Cloud Function, you need to generate an authentication token and insert it in the header:

```
import os
import json
import google.oauth2.id_token
import google.auth.transport.requests

os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = './my-service-account.json'
request = google.auth.transport.requests.Request()
audience = 'https://mylocation-myprojectname.cloudfunctions.net/MyFunctionName'
TOKEN = google.oauth2.id_token.fetch_id_token(request, audience)

MY_TASK_NAME = SimpleHttpOperator(
        task_id= 'MY_TASK_NAME',
        method='POST',
        http_conn_id='my_connection_id',
        endpoint='MyFunctionName',
        headers={'Authorization': f"Bearer {TOKEN}", "Content-Type": "application/json"},
        data=json.dumps({"key": "value"}),  # possible request parameters
        # dag=dag
    )
```

If **authentication is NOT required** to trigger the Cloud Function:

```
import os
import json

MY_TASK_NAME = SimpleHttpOperator(
        task_id= 'MY_TASK_NAME',
        method='POST',
        http_conn_id='my_connection_id',
        endpoint='MyFunctionName',
        headers={"Content-Type": "application/json"},
        data=json.dumps({"key": "value"}),  # possible request parameters
        # dag=dag
    )
```

In both cases remember to set `my_connection_id` in the Airflow Connections menu (Admin --> Connections). In the picture below is an example:

[image]

You can also trigger the Cloud Function using the `requests` python module (as before w/ or w/o authentication):

```
import os
import json
import requests
import google.oauth2.id_token
import google.auth.transport.requests

os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = './my-service-account.json'
request = google.auth.transport.requests.Request()
audience = 'https://mylocation-myprojectname.cloudfunctions.net/MyFunctionName'
TOKEN = google.oauth2.id_token.fetch_id_token(request, audience)

r = requests.post(
    'https://mylocation-myprojectname.cloudfunctions.net/MyFunctionName', 
    headers={'Authorization': f"Bearer {TOKEN}", "Content-Type": "application/json"},
    data=json.dumps({"key": "value"})  # possible request parameters
)
r.status_code, r.reason
```