# How to configure CloudFunctionInvokeFunctionOperator to call cloud function on composer(airflow)

Tags: google-cloud-functions, airflow, google-cloud-composer

I ran into the error to invoke cloud function by using CloudFunctionInvokeFunctionOperator like this.

line 915, in execute raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri) googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 404 when requesting https://cloudfunctions.googleapis.com/v1/projects/pongthorn/locations/asia-southeast1/functions/crypto-trading-to-bq:call?alt=json returned "Function crypto-trading-to-bq in region asia-southeast1 in project pongthorn does not exist". Details: "Function crypto-trading-to-bq in region asia-southeast1 in project pongthorn does not exist">

***I assump that I my made mistake at function id , What is functoin id  , the figure below is my cloud functoin and function name is   crypto-trading-to-bq

function id and function name , they are the same??????***

I set 3 variable names on JSON file and upload it to airflow as the following values
{
"project_id": "pongthorn",
"region_name": "asia-southeast1",
"function_name": "crypto-trading-to-bq"
}

[image: function name]

This is my code

```
import datetime

import airflow

from airflow.providers.google.cloud.operators.functions import (
    CloudFunctionDeleteFunctionOperator,
    CloudFunctionDeployFunctionOperator,
    CloudFunctionInvokeFunctionOperator,
)


YESTERDAY = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)

XProjdctID=airflow.models.Variable.get('project_id')
XRegion=airflow.models.Variable.get('region_name')
XFunction=airflow.models.Variable.get('function_name')

default_args = {
    'owner': 'Binance Trading Transaction',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'email': [''],
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': datetime.timedelta(minutes=5),
    'start_date': YESTERDAY,
}

with airflow.DAG(
        'bn_trading_flow',
        catchup=False,
        default_args=default_args,
        schedule_interval=datetime.timedelta(days=1)) as dag:
 
        call_crypto_trading_to_bq = CloudFunctionInvokeFunctionOperator(
        task_id = "load_crypto_trading_to_bq",
        location = XRegion,
        function_id = XFunction,
        input_data = {},
    )
```

Comment: In which region your Composer has been created ?

Comment: asia-southeast1

Comment: I don't know why it is not working. But according to the documentation, the `CloudFunctionInvokeFunctionOperator` is `to be used for testing purposes as very limited traffic is allowed.` Maybe you should use the `SimpleHttpOperator` instead and call your Cloud Function via API as it was designed for.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69131840/how-to-invoke-a-cloud-function-from-google-cloud-composer

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70174703/19489435